# Alias for submodules

Tags: git, bash, github

Was were using SVN prior and I have searched around but we use submodules differently I believe. At least when we branch. When we branch we want the submodules branched off as well as they are used in other applications, so I currently have two easy aliases.

```
sclone = "!f()  { branch=${1}; git checkout -b $branch; git submodule foreach -q --recursive git checkout -b $branch; }; f"

switch = "!f()  { branch=${1-master}; git checkout $branch; git submodule foreach -q --recursive git checkout $branch; }; f"
```

Those work fine however commit and merge are the stumbling blocks. I was trying to pass in the commit message but on the for each submodule I couldn't see how to pass in the message and maintain a return status.

So half solution I ended up with passing in the commit message but it requires vi edit for submodule commits, not quite optimal. I was hoping there was a way to still pass in the message but not exit the foreach loop on submodules if the first one returns 0. But I could not see away around the required single quotes and if I escape those with double quotes the OR does not work and it exits loop.

```
scommit = "!f() { git submodule foreach -q --recursive 'git commit -a || :' ; git commit -am \" $1 \";}; f"
```

And the second problem is the merge, that one I really need to pass in the branch being merged, and it works fine if there was no submodule changes or if all submodules had changes.

```
smerge = "!f()  { git merge $1; git submodule foreach -q --recursive git merge $1;}; f"
```

If someone with far superior git-fu could point me in the right direction or point out a better method would be much appreciated. Basically just trying to have single alias that auto does submodules (since we branch those) so prefer no third party solutions.

Also currently push/pull alias but these work fine.

```
spush = "!f()  { branch="$(git symbolic-ref head --short)"; git push origin $branch; git submodule foreach -q --recursive git push origin $branch; }; f"

spull = "!f()  { branch="$(git symbolic-ref head --short)"; git pull origin $branch; git submodule foreach -q --recursive git pull origin $branch; }; f"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could pass commit message as an argument, here is my solution, it requires manual directory routing though:

```
soeput = "! msg=\"${1-Minor update}\" ; echo \"gput for [bimg, bx, bgfx, soe]\" ; cd F:/Git/soe/bimg ; sh -c 'git add -A && git commit -m \"$0\" && git push' \"$msg\"; cd ../bx ; sh -c 'git add -A && git commit -m \"$0\" && git push' \"$msg\"; cd ../bgfx && sh -c 'git add -A && git commit -m \"$0\" && git push' \"$msg\"; cd .. && sh -c 'git add -A && git commit -m \"$0\" && git push' \"$msg\""
```